# Load xml data into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am trying to access data from a xml file into an html file, my JavaScript code is:

```
var xmlDoc;
var abc = new Array();

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlDoc = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlDoc.open("GET","wwww/../student.xml",false);
    xmlDoc.send("");
    xmlDoc = xmlDoc.responseXML;
}

var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    abc[i] = x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.write("value of abc["+i+"] is "+abc[i]);
}
```

But it's not working in IE. It displays an error i.e. "access is denied".

Can someone please tell me why is it not working in IE?

edited

the whole code is

```
 var xmlDoc;

 try
{

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

 {

  xmlDoc=new window.XMLHttpRequest();

 xmlDoc.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);

 xmlDoc.send("");xmlDoc=xmlDoc.responseXML;

} 

else if (ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"))

{

xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

xmlDoc.async=false;

xmlDoc.load("cd_catalog.xml");

}

}catch(e)

{

document.write("error");

}

document.write("<table border='1'>");

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");

for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){

document.write("<tr><td>");

document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

document.write("</td><td>");document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

document.write("</td></tr>");

}

document.write("</table>");
```

i got this code from here http://www.scribd.com/doc/19290029/XML-Javascript-Tutorial

it is there by the name **Load an XML String - A Cross browser Example**

i am not able to run it in IE7.. can someone hrlp

Comment: The request is in the same domain?

Comment: can u please tell me what do you mean by this sorry i am not that good with javascript

Comment: when you do `xmlDoc.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);` you're searching for a document with the name of cd_catalog.xml. That document exists in your site?, is the rute (url) to it correct?

Comment: yes the xml file exits on the site

Comment: this code is just not working in IE, it is working in firefox.